# etrade curl login using windows cmd to curl

Tags: curl, etrade-api

etrade api login

my current command line from cmd.exe

C:\etrade\bin\curl.exe  -S  -s -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data {\"USER\":\"userid\", \"PASSWORD\":\"password\", \"\":\"\", \"TARGET\":\"/e/t/\"} -X POST "https://us.etrade.com/login.fcc"

** I have tried using post different ways. grabbing pre cookies **
** CMD CURL Execution is below, it fails. I have tried using json and form type. all have failed **

** so if anyone has a correction that will make this work it would be great. i only need this execution to grab the token verifier for my ETRADE API.**

trying to get to the access token automated, working on access token after verifier, which is currently failing. with invalid signature.